# Apply properties to multiple html elements

Tags: html, angular

How to apply properties like resizable to all elements without setting it for each one separately?

```
<column field="Date" width="130px" [resizable]="true" [sortable]="true" header="Date"></column>
<column field="Time" width="100px" [resizable]="true" [sortable]="false" header="Time"></column>
<column field="PKG" width="150px" [hidden]="true" [resizable]="true" [sortable]="true" header="PKG"></column>
```

Comment: Consider an ngFor?

Comment: I did, but I am looking for a solution which does not require me to change the code behind. They all need custom a custom width which I then would also have to feed from javascript.

Comment: I believe that's the most elegant solution in this case. Map your column to a class with field, width, etc... as attributes, except the ones that are always the same. In your controller create an array of this class, in this case with 3 elements. In your template, just use an *ngFor to run through these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property to column selector and that should apply for all columns.

Comment: I should have mentioned that <column> is third party. I could extend the selector but that would be more effort than keeping it this way.